# How to know if transaction is failed due to insufficient balance?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I want to know if it is possible to know from "error" object returned by geth  that the error it was due to insufficient balance (something to compare with)

I have a js code like that:

```
mycontract.storeData("some-data")
     .then(res => {
          // transaction confirmed 
            })
     .catch(error => {
     // I want to know the cause if the error (programmatically) like error.statusCode ... ?
  })
```

Comment: When you investigate things, while trying to gather some info that could help you with your question, you could by the least `console.log(error)` and share it with us! BTW, there's no way to tell if the error was due to insufficient balance, but there IS a way to deduce the answer to that questions from the `error` object along with the current balance of your account.

Comment: error message is widely known ("insufficient funds for gas * price + value”), the question is about how to identify error programmatically

Comment: Sounds like you already know the answer to your question then.

Comment: How ? I am asking if there a way to identify the error programmatically

Comment: I dont want to compare error message with this string  "insufficient funds for gas * price + value”, i think isn't reliable

Comment: How about `if (error.message.includes("insufficient funds for gas * price + value"))`?

Comment: I will use it if there is no other reliable solutions.. I am not sure that next Geth version will keep the exacltly same message.

Comment: Well, there should typically be a response object, from which you can extract the account address, the gas, the gas price and the value. Then, you could simply check if the account's balance is smaller than gas * gas price + value, which would give you a unanimous indication as to whether or not this is the error which has occurred.

Comment: Unfortunatly isn't, is just an error object that contains the famous message: "insufficient funds for gas * price + value"

Comment: Switch to web3.js v1.2.x, and follow [this example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id23). In particularly, read about the error-handler at the bottom of this example, which is designated to catch exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Switch from web3 v0.x (which you're apparently on) to web3 v1.2.x, and then follow [this example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id23).

In particularly, read about the error-handler at the bottom of this example, which appears to be designated to catch exactly what you're after:

> `.on('error', console.error);`
>
> If there's an out-of-gas error, then the second parameter is the receipt.

EDIT - the error-handler example above is rather poor; let me rewrite it:

```
.on('error', function(error, receipt) {
    if (receipt !== undefined) {
        // handle out-of-gas errors
    }
    else {
        // handle all other errors
    }
});
```

Comment: but this catch any type of errors, yes ?

Comment: @maroodb: I suggest that you try it on first, see what you get inside the function and all. From my understanding of the comment `If there's an out-of-gas error, then the second parameter is the receipt`, the answer to your question is Yes (because it implies that there are other types of errors).

Comment: I tried it ofcourse, I have an example of smart contract methods that it run 'revert()' if some condition, and here the code above log the revert error

Comment: @maroodb: Is that a question?

Comment: I meant when I tried this code even errors related to smart contract (revert, require..) they were catched, so it does the same thing as using promise (catch(error)..)

Comment: @maroodb: See updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't resolve the problem, the receipt is always 'undefined'.. I think this resolve the error of 'running out of gas', in our case the balance has 0 ETH at the beginning ..

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate way to know why mined transaction failed is to trace it.  In Geth you may do this using [debug.traceTransaction()](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_tracetransaction).

Comment: But in the case of "insufficient funds for gas * price + value”, there is no transaction yet to debug

Comment: Yes, but this situation is easy to recognize, because sender's balance, transaction value, gas limit, and gas price are known.

Comment: but I am asking about "insufficient funds for gas * price + value” error, and here it doesn't help

Comment: Original question was about transaction that failed because of insufficient balance.  The fact that transaction failed implies that it was mined.

Comment: It cant be mined while wallet hasn't fund, anyway thank you

Comment: One may call some contract (e.g. multisig wallet) from account that has some ether, the contract may then try to perform internal transaction and this internal transaction may fail because contract's balance is insufficient.  Such situation would be tricky to detect, and I really thought that the question was about this.